# Design about returning reference to non exist data

Tags: c++, reference

I ran into this design problem. Here's the story:

I have a base class that defines a few methods like this:

```
virtual double & f(double x);
```

The base class will call one of them to ask for the reference to some data in subclass when answering some queries. The problem is, these f methods return an optional piece of data in subclass. In other words, depending on the subclass, what f is asking to return may not exist at all. The logic in the base class can guarantee that it will not call such f() on a subclass when it doesn't exist, so in principle this subclass doesn't need to implement this method, but I don't want to make the method pure virtual because the subclass needs to be instantiable regardless. Inconveniently the return type of f needs to be reference so I can't simply return some junk value.

So basically I'm looking for a "elegant" way to return a dummy reference, that will not be called anyway if the program works correctly, but ideally would help debugging by catching mistake calls. The signature of f is important for readability so ideally I don't want to change it.

I suppose I can declare a dummy static double DATA_NOT_EXIST variable in the class and return it, but it looks a bit ugly. Any better ideas? What's your favorite way to return a "null" reference when you have to?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:

I want to keep these methods in base class, although they do seem better off declared in subclasses instead, because the base class is trying to handle some logic that's not applicable to all subclasses (is this itself a bad design?). Something like this: the base class represents a mouse, and the optional data in the subclasses represent left/middle/right buttons. Any particular subclass may not have certain buttons, but anyway the base class still handles button clicks, with the assumption that there may or may not be buttons.

---

Edit:
Here's some source code to illustrate what I mean to do. In base class:

```
#include <cassert>
struct Base
{
  double & basef(int x)
  {
    assert(x >= 0 && x < 20);
    if (x < 10) return f1(x);
    else return f2(x);
  }
  virtual double & f1(int x);
  virtual double & f2(int x);
};

struct Sub1 : Base
{
  double & f1(int x) { return a[x]; }
  double & f2(int x) { return b[x - 10]; }
  double a[10];
  double b[10];
};

struct Sub2 : Base
{
  double & f1(int x) { return a[x]; }
  double & f2(int x) { /* nothing to return here! */ }
  double a[10];
};
```

Comment: Why not just put these functions in a subclass? If they cannot be implemented in every subclass then they have no place being in the superclass (in general).

Comment: Overall, your design seems flawed, but if you can't change it, the best thing to do would probably be to just `assert(false)` in the subclasses where `f` should never be called.

Comment: They need to be called by a base class dispatcher. That dispatcher has to be in the base class. Think of the base class as representing something like a mouse, and the optional data as e.g. left/middle/right button. Not all mouses have all keys, but it still makes better sense to assume such common scheme in the base class and let the base class handle the key clicks.

Comment: I see your point (or at least, I think I do). You have two reasonable options -- 1) move `f` into a subclass, and then explicitly downcast when you are sure that it will be available (this is equivalent to what you are already doing, but it makes it clearer that this is how the code works), 2) figure out what the common interface is, and put the "dispatching" code (or whatever) in the subclass (perhaps with a common implementation as a free function somewhere).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't think I can go with (1) because even if which data is available is known, it is still unknown which subclass to down cast to because there will be many subclasses. Could you elaborate on (2) please?

Comment: @fang: If you present an example code snippet from the base class that calls `f()`, and example client code that calls this base-class function, it will help us figure out the right way to refactor your base class.

Comment: In (1), you don't have to downcast to the exact class, just to a subclass which has `f` and which all the other classes with `f` further subclass from. I can't really elaborate on (2) much without knowing the exact operation that the code is meant to perform, but basically, there *must* be a common interface/operation that you want to be able to perform on any base object... if you dispatch this operation to the sub-classes, then the subclasses can implement the operation themselves, taking advantage of the additional data that they contain, where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm afraid it's still not clear exactly what classes are trying to do what -- e.g. is the base class implementing some kind of event loop, or is the client code (that calls the base class) doing that?  Please post code.

Comment: "the base class is trying to handle some logic that's not applicable to all subclasses (is this itself a bad design?)" -- well, the snide answer is "Yes" :-P  But most design involves tradeoffs, and sometimes the benefit of a perfectly LSP-obeying class hierarchy is outweighed by the simplicity of an inheritance-abusing design that saves many lines of code.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I like your comment about tradeoffs:) I posted some mockup code to show what I'm trying to do, because the real code involves too much domain-specific stuff; but I feel it's still not clearly showing the problem. I'll see if I can post more in the morning

Comment: Thanks :) It would be useful to see how the client code uses the base class, but I think I can already suggest: Why not simply make `basef()` a public, non-virtual function that calls a *single* protected, virtual function called `f()` that is defined by each derived class? That way the client code must call `basef()`, which can still do any pre/post processing that you want to do for every type of mouse, while allowing each particular type of mouse to handle the `int x` parameter however it wants.

Comment: Of course there are tradeoffs. I've written the "obvious" way to do [(1)](http://liveworkspace.org/code/fef1d2f83ebaa85da92beff75d978324) and [(2)](http://liveworkspace.org/code/206364fa78cf2b2e5967023a016cd932) given your example code, I'm not sure how much it helps in your real situation, but it shows the principle.

Comment: Regarding the option of returning a reference to some `DATA_NON_EXISTING` dummy: You can declare this as a local, but static variable inside the function: `double &f2(int x) { static double dummy = 0; return dummy; }`. I wouldn't find that ugly (it can be confusing though, if somebody actually calls that function and gets `0` returned without knowing that the function should never have been called in the first place. Another potential problem is that the caller will be able to acutally modify the value of `dummy`).

Comment: Throw an exception. Or change the return type to `boost::optional<double&>`. Or change the design fundamentally. The three usual safe approaches.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, This is probably what Mankarse meant by (2).

Comment: @Mankarse, I appreciate the options you provided. Without actual domain specific info these two options indeed sound attractive. However I want to avoid requiring the subclasses to derive from an unintuitive specialization of base class based on availability of certain data (domain specific); and I want to avoid requiring subclasses to re-implement the logic in basef() that's the same for each subclass as long as the data exists (code's exactly the same). But since I'm imposing so much design constraints I probably have excluded a satisfy-all answer myself already...

Comment: I like @Mankarse's (2), except (as I said), assuming that you want the code in `basef()` to apply to all possible subclasses, I would put the sole implementation of `basef()` directly in the base class, and make it non-virtual.  The base class would also declare a pure-virtual protected method called `f()` which each subclass would define.  That way you can prevent client code from calling `f()` directly, which allows you to enforce a certain amount of policy in the base class.  (E.g. if you want to always do some logging before or after, that can go in the base class's `basef()`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options, none require you introduce undefined behavior into your program by dereferencing null pointers as has been suggested by two answers now.

1) Throw an exception. Take away the unpredictability and make it part of your design:

```
// default implementation in base class
virtual double& f2(int x)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("No value defined");
}
```

2) Use `boost::optional<double&>`:

```
// default implementation in base class
virtual boost::optional<double&> f2(int x)
{
    return boost::optional<double&>();
}

// call-site
auto value = x->f2(0);
if (value)
    do_something(*value);
```

3) Use `double*` (poor-man's `boost::optional`):

```
// default implementation in base class
virtual double* f2(int x)
{
    return nullptr;
}

// same call-site as before
```

4) Fundamentally change the design to avoid the situation.

All of these are better solutions because they're reliable and predictable.

Comment: Could you quickly explain what boost is doing behind the scene in (2)?

Comment: @fang: Basically number three, actually, when the `T` in `boost::optional<T>` is a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

```
double& Dummy() { return *(double*)nullptr; }
```

If your compiler is smart enough to realize that this is a nullptr access and warns about it, try using another value that is likely to cause a crash, like anything <4096 (reasonably modern systems should have the first memory page completely offlimits to catch nullpointer dereferences), ~0 or something similar, or make the pointer a global variable.

Of course, I would usually do something like

```
double& Dummy() { ASSERT(false); }
```

and only return the reference if the compiler doesn't know about functions that don't return.

Comment: This is the same  as a downvoted and deleted answer on this question. Do not introduce undefined behavior into your program to solve a problem.

Comment: @GManNickG: Is it actually UB?  I suspect it might only be UB if the reference is actually accessed during a particular execution (similar to how you're allowed to write `((struct foo *) NULL)->somefield` if all you actually do is apply `sizeof` to it), but I'm not sure.  If so, and if no execution ever actually accesses it when the ref is NULL, then no UB would arise.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Standard-wise, it's intended to be UB, though last I looked it was an active issue of whether this should be UB: `int* i = nullptr; *i;`, since it doesn't do anything with the value. The `sizeof` example is  okay because the argument to `sizeof` is explicitly specified to be non-evaluated. Regardless, yes, if the code is never run then there is no UB, but the point is if you're going to run code in a bad situation, why make it worse by doing something unpredictable or ill-defined? Just throw an exception.